# How to use Firebug CSS on dynamically appearing components?

Tags: dynamic, dojo, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a Javascript Based site, which uses the Dojo Framework.

I am using a [DataPicker](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html#id3). I wish to change the background color of the datePicker, and hence I wish to look at where in the CSS is the color being set, so that I can override it in my CSS.

Usually I use FireBug and 'Inspect Element in FireBug' to view the HTML and CSS together. (or even Google Chrome's developer tools)

However this datepicker is a dynamically created component, and If I right click, or move my mouse into the Firebug window, the date picker is shutdown/destroyed. (You can check out the sample on the linked page itself)

Is there a way to inspect the CSS on these kinds of dynamic elements, using Firebug, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I've found for the dijit popup widgets is (using chrome)

1. Open the popup (in this case the date picker)
2. Right click on the element
3. Select "Inspect Element" from context menu
4. Chrome will open and transfer focus to the developer tools without blurring the focus of the page, keeping the popup open, allowing you to modify attributes and css rules and getting instant feedback.

Comment: I can swear that I tried this yesterday, and it did not work, but today it Works!